# How to insert large documents in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to store a large JSON document larger than 16MB (which is the size limit per document) in MongoDB, but due to the size limit i am unable to do so. How can I store such large documents in MongoDB? I know GridFS API can be an option, but after a lot of struggle, I am still unable to figure out how to use GridFS and what are the right commands to insert and retrieve data using GridFS. Any help in using GridFS or any other alternative to store large JSON documents would be much appreciated.

I am using Python's PyMongo package.

Thanks!

Comment: is modifying the schema an option?

Comment: @serbia99 yes it can be modified. Please share your suggestions!

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb. Check this out. Try to redesign your schema to something like this if possible.

Answer (score -3):

> There are so many methods to store large data in MongoDB

```
var Data = {
    "userID": "1",
    "userData": {
        "firstName": "Test Firest Name",
        "lastName": "Test Last Name",
        "number":{
            "phNumber": "9999999991",
            "cellNumber": "8888888888",
        },
        "address": {
            "Geo": {
                "latitude": 15.40,
                "longtitude": -70.90
            },
            "city": "surat",
            "state": "gujarat",
            "contry": "india"
        },
        "product": {
            "game": {
                "GTA": true,
                "DOTA": true
            },
            "television": {
                "TV": true,
                "PlayStation": true
                "Xbox": false
            }
        },
    },
    "key": "ANbcsgYSIDncsSK"
};
db.collection("[collection Name]").insertMany(Data)
```

Comment: The size limit is 16MB. Is this data larger than 16MB? Probably not

Comment: Documents must be a non-empty list